# Using R I want to create a table showing member weekday rides and causal week day rides

Tags: r, count, as.date

I have df with 3 million rows. I want to group by member_casual, convert the date to day of the week and get a count of observations (frequency) for each day of the week grouped by member.

```
 member_casual  date
 member         11/12/2021
 member         11/13/2021
 casual         10/15/2021
 member          9/3/2021
 casual          6/23/2021
 ...             ...
```

I want a  df or table that will output like this

```
  member        Sunday     114999
                Monday     145987
                Tuesday    89433
                ...
  casual        Sunday     18448
                Monday     111748
                ...
```

I can get the individual, member or casual, but not group in one df/table.

```
df_daym <- filter( df, member_casual == "member" )

df_daym <- count( weekdays((as.Date(df_daym$started_at))))
df_daym
```

Which produces this just for the member

```
x.       freq

Friday    307671            
Monday    268096            
Saturday  324283            
Sunday    266256            
Thursday  301321            
Tuesday   285632            
Wednesday 306113
```

I want to combine them into one output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wday` from lubridate to get the weekday and then `group by` and `summarise` from dplyr for the rest.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
mutate(weekday = wday(date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE) %>%
group_by(weekday, member_casual) %>%
summarise(n = n())
```

Answer (score 1):

Usage of `janitor::tabyl()` in such cases in highly recommended.  Try this

```
df %>% mutate(weekday = weekdays(date)) %>% tabyl(weekday, member_casual)
```

---

check on a dummy data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(member_casual = sample(c('member', 'casual'), 1000, T),
                 date = as.Date('2010-01-01') + sample(1:10000, 1000))
library(janitor)
df %>% mutate(weekday = weekdays(date)) %>% tabyl(weekday, member_casual)

   weekday casual member
    Friday     64     66
    Monday     76     81
  Saturday     82     79
    Sunday     61     69
  Thursday     77     57
   Tuesday     59     71
 Wednesday     75     83
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the date to 'Date' class, use `weekdays` to get day of the week and use `table` to get the count.

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, '%m/%d/%Y')
table(df$member_casual, weekdays(df$date))
```